# Camera orthographic size certain width

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, orthographic

How do we can set a certain size of units for defining the width of the Orthographic size of the camera in the portrait mode?

I want to set the horizontal dimension to the **5 meters** **exactly** from the center-left to the center-right of the screen for any mobile device? how can I achieve this? I've found this piece of code from a video clip but I don't understand it and I think it does not help me since I don't have a game field and also my game world will be generated automatically during the game (it's an infinite 2D scrolling game).

```
[SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer gameField;
void Start()
{
    float screenRatio = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;
    float targetRatio = gameField.bounds.size.x / gameField.bounds.size.y;
   
    if (screenRatio > targetRatio)
    {
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = gameField.bounds.size.y / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        float differenceInSize = targetRatio / screenRatio;
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = gameField.bounds.size.y / 2 * differenceInSize;
    }
}
```

I don't know why unity doesn't handle these issues automatically?

Comment: So you essentially want to archive that all players on all screen sizes see the same part of the game?

Comment: @DanielM, Yes and exactly 5 meters.

Comment: Are you setting an isometric view or side flat view?

Comment: @joreldraw, simple orthographic projection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the video you have been talking about and it is actually pretty simple. For reference, it is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xXlnSetHPM&ab_channel=PressStart) video. I will try to explain it to you.
These 5 boxes represent all content that you want to show on your screen. You want your camera to always adjust itself so it fits all of those boxes inside of it.

[image]

To archive this you have to multiply the width of our boxes (all of our boxes are 1 meter wide in all dimensions) by the screen height devided by the screen width. You then want to divide that number by two.

```
boxes.width * screen.height / screen.width * 0.5
```

In our code it looks like this:

```
public float sizeInMeters;

void Start()
{
    float orthoSize = sizeInMeters * Screen.height / Screen.width * 0.5f;

    Camera.main.orthographicSize = orthoSize;
}
```

If you want to have five meters to the left and right from the middle then put in 10 into the `sizeInMeters` variable. If your total screen width from left to right should only cover 5 meters you have to put in 5 into the `sizeInMeters` variable.
The `if` inside of your code is only there if you want the user to be able to flip his phone into a vertical position.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll test your script